# Datatable.js + POSTing data PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, datatables

I'm trying to setup my datatable to POST to the contents of it's rows into my PHP script so that I can store it in a database.

I have a working HTML page, which when I click "+ Add Mapping" a BS modal appears and I can add a row to the datatable.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var t = $('#parameters_config').DataTable();
        $('#add_new_mapping').on('click', function() {
            $('#add_field_mapping').modal('hide');
            var wb_field = $("#add_field_mapping #wb_field").val();
            var adobe_field = $("#add_field_mapping #adobe_field").val();
            t.row.add([
                adobe_field,
                wb_field,
            ]).draw();
            $('#add_new_field_mapping').trigger("reset");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This all works perfectly. I now would like to retrieve all data rows and POST them to my script so that I can process the submitted data and store. So far, I've come up with this based on information provided:

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#parameters').submit(function(event) {                   
                  var table = $('#parameters_config').DataTable();
                  var dataToSend = table
                    .rows()
                    .data();
                  console.log( 'Data', dataToSend);
                  alert( 'There are '+dataToSend.length+' row(s) of data in this table');
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{$this->homeURL}',
                    data: dataToSend,
                    dataType: 'json',
                  });
              });
            });
        </script>
```

In my console window I see the following returned for "dataToSend" but no actual data!

[Array[2], context: Array[1], selector: Object, ajax: Object]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is `$this` supposed to be here?

Comment: $this->homeURL references to a variable in my PHP code, it's set to something like https://secure.workbooks.com. It's the URL of the current script.

Comment: Right, but what's it doing in the middle of a JavaScript file?

Comment: Well... my understanding is the AJAX call needs to posted somewhere so it can be processed?

Comment: It's also based on the below information provided...

Comment: Obviously the AJAX call needs an endpoint, but JavaScript itself has no idea what `$this` means. If you're evaluating that arbitrarily on the PHP side of things you have huge problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Where the examples went wrong**

The two examples you linked in your post aren't really related to what you're trying to do (from what I can gather about your goal).

The first example is about how to obtain data from the server with a POST instead of the default GET, and has nothing to do with *sending* data to the server for some purpose.

The second example is about serverside processing, which is where you have pagination, ordering, sorting, filtering, and all other DataTables features handled in **your own** server code where you then send the results to the client (which is pretty complicated and unless you have a huge number of rows, unnecessary).

**Therefore, remove `serverSide: true`**!

**Your Goal**

What you actually want to do (I think) is send your data to a php script so that you can do something with it. This is not handled by any DataTables API call, but is a fairly simple feature to implement. All you really need is a function that will make an AJAX call that will send the data to the script.

**Solution**

The way you can do this is by obtaining the data with the `t.data()` [API call](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()), and then sending it with an ajax request. It might look like this:

```
function sendData(){
    var dataToSend = t.data();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'URL OF SCRIPT HERE',
        data: dataToSend
    });
}
```

Then you simply have to call `sendData()` whenever it is that you want to send the data. Of course, you'll have to ensure that your controller handles the data correctly, but that's a different matter entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I've updated my question based on your response. I am however still having no luck at retrieving the actual data, I've managed to get the number of rows but no actual data... help!

Comment: @JamieLowe What is contained in dataToSend (try stepping through to find out) and what is sent in JSON (use dev tools or fiddler to see the contents of the JSON)?